# Create a new column by executing regular expression on existing column

Tags: regex, psql

I have column with data as follows:

`p=Chicago, IL|q=rental houses`

My goal is to obtain
`Chicago IL rental houses` as the outcome by running regular expression on the column via a select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below regx on string

```
/p=(.*)|q=(.*)/
```

Then join 2 substrings with spaces.

If you want get result from select query you can use select with concat or concat_ws function  instead.